# How to use defN in Math.FFT in Haskell? How to construct a multi-dimensional CArray?

Tags: arrays, haskell

I need to DFT a image and the `dft` function accepts `CArray` as its parameter. But I don't know how to construct a multi-dimensional `CArray`. Could someone help me and give a demo about how to construct a multi-dimensional `CArray` from some fundamental data structure like `[]`?

Comment: `CArray` is an instance of [`Data.Array.IArray.IArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html#t:IArray), meaning you can use the `array`, `accumArray`, `listArray` functions as you would to create any other instance of `IArray`.

Comment: Could you please give a demo like constructing a two-dimension array? And point out which parameter indicates its dimension. Thank you.

Comment: `listArray ((dim1_lower_bound, dim2_lower_bound), (dim1_upper_bound, dim2_upper_bound)) [0..]`

Comment: I use your method and have solved my problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ZhangjieCao, Could you please post your answer on how to use the `dft` function? The function has type `(Math.FFT.Base.FFTWReal r, Data.Ix.Shapable.Shapable i, Ix i) => Data.Array.CArray.Base.CArray i (Complex r) -> Data.Array.CArray.Base.CArray i (Complex r)`

Answer (score 1):

The construction functions are generic over the choice of `IArray` representation, and are available in [`Data.Array.IArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html):

```
import Data.Array.CArray
import qualified Data.Array.IArray as Arr

-- | A 10x10 2-dimensional array stored row by row in a list -- your "fundamental data structure like []"
rowByRow :: [Double]
rowByRow = [0..100]

-- | A 10x10 d-dimensional CArray. The coordinates start at 0.
carray :: CArray (Int, Int) Double
carray = Arr.listArray ((0, 0), (9, 9)) rowByRow
```